# Image of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for 64-bit

Tags: 12.04, system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my Lenovo ThinkPad that has 64-bit architecture, but where do I find a 64-bit version of 12.04?

It doesn't seem to appear on this [site](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.5/)

Comment: I can see plenty of amd64 links.

Comment: For those whi still can't see it - here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.5/ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the link to [Ubuntu 12.04 64bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.5-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent) but its legit torrent file

or visit [official site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads), at the bottom you will links to all supported ubuntu releases

---

if above links are not working, here is [mirror link](http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu-iso/12.04/) from [University of Maryland](http://umd.edu/)

Comment: Here's the torrent file link: http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.5/ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent

Comment: @muru about other torrent link, can I give it also but ill mention that it belongs to other torrent site ? ill keep both link

Comment: If you must, there are mirrors of the release repositories you can use. Not some pirated torrents site. You can post a question on [meta] whether its ok. See: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors

Comment: @muru now i gave a  link from a legit university of maryland, official website link is also given